# cURL with PHP - HTTP cURL to HTTPS

Tags: php, curl, cross-domain

I have the following bit of PHP, **it works locally (via apache and localhost)** but not on my hosting - `$response` is always empty:

```
function get_data($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }

    $api_key = 'my_api_key'; 

    $randomString = generateRandomString(10);
    $endLabel = sha1(md5($randomString));
    $user_id = $endLabel;

    $amount_doge = '5'; 

    $url = "https://dogeapi.com/wow/?api_key=".$api_key."&a=get_new_address&address_label=".$user_id;
    $response = get_data($url);
```

I wondered if this could be because I'm hosted on HTTP (no SSL option) and I'm calling a HTTPS domain? If so, is there a way around this? I've tried `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` but it doesn't seem to do anything :(

Comment: did u try CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=False

Comment: @user1844933 - Afraid that just returns nothing as well :(

Comment: did u install  libcurl package in your server? :)

Comment: Yeah, cURL is installed correctly. Version 7

Comment: Downvoted. I would like to know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `echo curl_error($ch)` after `$data = curl_exec($ch);` to see what curl says
it wil lreport you what happened

Comment: Ahh, I'm now getting `error:14077458:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)`

Comment: try to set this option `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);`

Comment: WONDERFUL - I love you! <3

Comment: that is an old openssl bug during handshake